# Force a Mac OS X 32/64-bit universal binary to run 32-bit on an old OS version only?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I want to ship a *single* 32/64-bit universal binary of my desktop Mac OS X Cocoa app. I don't want to ship two versions.

I want it to run as a 64-bit process on Snow Leopard.

However, if the app is launched on Leopard, I want to always force it to run as a 32-bit process.

NOTE: I know that in the Finder 'Get Info' window you can click the 'Open in 32-bit mode' checkbox to achieve this. That's nice, but what I really want is a way to *automatically, always* force this behavior on *Leopard only*. On Snow Leopard the app should run 64-bit unless the user wants to change the setting mentioned above.

Can this be done? If so, how? thx.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set the [minimum system version per architecture key](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/PListKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-113253-BAJDHACB) in your Info.plist file :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not usable for un-bundled command line tools, because embedded Info.plist (linker options `-createsect __TEXT __info_plist path/to/Info.plist`) is ignored on 10.5, and furthermore OS X uses the Info.plist hwne started via Cocoa interfaces (e.g. by clicking in Finder) and certainly not when typing the command on command line....